# Inner join with one row of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join

```
**Table Employee** 

Id    Name
1     EmpName1
2     EmpName2
3     EmpName3

**Table EmpDeptHistory**

Id    EmpId    Dept        Date
1     1        Housing     2015-03-02
2     2        Finance     2015-01-03
3     1        WareHouse   2015-05-02
4     2        Housing     2015-02-06
5     3        WareHouse   2015-02-02
6     1        Housing     2015-05-01
7     2        Finance     2015-01-02
8     2        Housing     2015-05-04
9     2        Finance     2015-05-02
10    1        WareHouse   2015-03-08
11    1        Housing     2015-02-20
```

I need find the recent dept with which every employee worked. Also I need to find for individual employee by passing EmpId

The following query returns only one employee and not all :(

```
SELECT e.id, edh.dept,edh.date
FROM Employee e
  inner join (select top 1 eh.empid, eh.dept, eh.date
              from EmpDeptHistory eh
              order by eh.date desc) as edh
    on e.id=edh.empid
```

yes, I understand the top 1 will give the emp id based on date, hence only one employee details is show. I am not sure how to get all the employee recent department.

```
select e.id,edh.dept,edh.date
from employee e
  inner join EmpDeptHistory edh
    on e.id = (Select eh.empid, eh.dept, eh.date   
               from EmpDeptHistory eh
               where e.id=eh.empid
               order by eh.date desc)
```

The above throws

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables,     subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP,
>   OFFSET or FOR XML is   also specified.

Comment: What is `recent dept`?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri the dept with which  the employee worked recently based on Date. For emp id 1, warehouse is recent dept. (Id-3 in second table)

Comment: By "the recent dept" do you mean the latest / last dept that an employee worked in?

Comment: @TechJerk ok, I'll post an answer based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) to run the right-hand subquery once for each left-hand row:

```
SELECT e.id, edh.dept,edh.date
FROM Employee e cross apply ( select top 1 eh.empid, eh.dept, eh.date from  
EmpDeptHistory eh where eh.empid = e.id order by eh.date desc) as edh
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CTE and a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT e.id, edh.dept, edh.date,
           rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY edh.EmpId ORDER BY edh.date DESC)
    FROM Employee e inner join EmpDeptHistory edh  
       on e.id = edh.empid
)
SELECT id, dept, date
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd878/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

For the *latest* department for each employee, you can do it like so:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM EmpDeptHistory t1 INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT EmpId, MAX(Date) [Date] 
   FROM EmpDeptHistory 
   GROUP BY EmpId
) AS t2 
    ON t1.EmpId = t2.EmpId AND t1.Date = t2.Date
```

EmpId can be put into a where clause if needed.